# XPath relative to a node - how select the current node?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a system which evaluates XPath expressions (filters) relative to a node within the XML document. Normally a filter would match some sub node and check whether it exists. E.g., `./div[contains(@class, 'soldout')]` to filter out already sold out products.

I now want to express a filter expression based upon the current node. I tried the following:

```
.[contains(@class, 'soldout')]
```

But the system tells me that this is no valid XPath.

What's the correct way to express "current node" or "context node"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need self axis. It works like this :

path to the node/self::element to evaluate[predicate]

```
/path to the node/self::*[contains(@class, 'soldout')]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an unfortunate bug in the XPath 1.0 grammar that "`.`" and "`..`" can't be followed by a predicate (this was fixed in 2.0). It arises because of the rule

```
[4] Step ::=    AxisSpecifier NodeTest Predicate*   
                | AbbreviatedStep
```

(where an `AbbreviatedStep` is `.` or `..`)

So although it says in the spec that "`.`" is equivalent to `self::node()`, that's not strictly true, because `self::node()` can be followed by a predicate, and `.` can't.

Comment: Thank you for the theoretical background, I'm always interested in why something is the way it is! +1